# No internet with self hosted Wireguard VPN on Cloud VM

Tags: vpn, troubleshooting, cloud, wireguard, self-hosting

I setup a Wireguard VPN server on a Google Cloud VM but when connecting to it with the iOS client (running latest OS and app) nothing loads via the internet when the VPN is on (no browsing, emails, social media, etc), as if I don’t have an internet connection. What could be causing this, or how can I troubleshoot? Note: I am a beginner, and apologize if I am using incorrect terminology, feel free to correct me.

I followed this guide exactly, except with iOS as the client instead of Android: https://dhanangw.medium.com/setup-wireguard-vpn-in-google-cloud-platform-67ddb692b2d8

Comment: Please describe all steps you took to set up the VPN server.

Comment: @DanielB thanks for the reply. I followed this guide exactly, except with iOS as the client instead of Android: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj4pbz75Yr2AhXUkokEHWP8ANsQFnoECAMQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdhanangw.medium.com%2Fsetup-wireguard-vpn-in-google-cloud-platform-67ddb692b2d8&usg=AOvVaw2ip7pR6Vvhn9ZeWHV9IjKQ

Comment: In this guide, an iptables rule with `MASQUERADE` is set up. Please verify that it is present on the GCP virtual machine: `sudo iptables -t nat -vnL POSTROUTING`. Also check again that the interface name in this rule really is the VM’s public network interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Daniel B's right, you don't need `canIpForward` in your case. The guide you followed is good -- but it does have one misstep: It directs you to use the server's WireGuard IP address, `10.0.0.1`, in the client config, as the client's WireGuard IP address -- whereas the client's address should instead be `10.0.0.2`.

You can fix that by editing the client's config in your iOS WireGuard app. Turn off the the WireGuard tunnel, and edit the `Address` field of the interface to this:

```
10.0.0.2/24
```

Turn the tunnel back on, and it should start working.

---

The Google Cloud-specific issue you may be encountering is you need to turn on IP forwarding on your VM configuration via the [`canIpForward`](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-routes#canipforward) property of the VM. You can do this from the Google Cloud console when you create the VM, or with the `gcloud compute instances update-from-file ...` CLI command for a running VM (see the [Update VM Properties](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/update-instance-properties) documentation).

In addition, within the VM itself, make sure you also turn on the Linux `net.ipv4.ip_forward` property (ie run `sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`), which you still need regardless of cloud platform.

Comment: The GCP rule should not be necessary when NAT is set up properly.

Comment: I already did both @Justin Ludwig

Comment: Thanks, it works after I corrected the interface IP! I have also let the tutorial author know of the mistake.